# SQL Server after insert Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Ins] ON  [databasename].[dbo].[tablename] 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @timerange as INT
    SET @timerange = 40
    UPDATE [databasename].[dbo].[tablename]
        SET [column2] = (SELECT TOP 1 [column1]
                                FROM [CIMPLICITY].[dbo].[tablename] AS s2
                                WHERE DATEDIFF(MI,s2.[timestamp],[databasename].[dbo].[tablename].[timestamp]) <= ROUND([databasename].[dbo].[tablename].[column3],0))
    WHERE
        DATEDIFF(MI,[timestamp], SYSDATETIME()) < @timerange
END
GO
```

After adding a new row to the table, the trigger must recalculate the value in column 2.
The value in column 2 = the value in column 1 at offset backwards by minute equal to the value in column 3.

Trigger works, but the application that fill the table with data, stops working after the trigger.
I think that the error in the trigger code.

In advance I thank and sorry for my googletranslate english :)

Comment: Can you define: stops working. Is there an error message?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your problem is that the trigger updates *every* record in the table, rather than just the inserted record(s).

If so, add another `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE [primary key column] IN 
    (SELECT [primary key column] from inserted)
```

`inserted` is the alias for all records handled by the current `INSERT` statement.

Comment: i'm try modify WHERE conditions to      WHERE
  [timestamp] IN (SELECT [timestamp] from inserted) , and value in last row has updated, but an application that updates the data in this database anyway has stopped working

Answer (score 0):

Probably trigger recursion. Check the TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL and return if value is larger than one:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182737%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: Not possible. An `insert` and `update` cannot conflict with each other.

Answer (score -1):

I'm find a solution to the problem: it was necessary to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` after `BEGIN`.
I do not know why, but it working :)